# how to use lookup on array object mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm new on mongodb. so I try design the schema for my collection is like below

> all the ObjectId is not real

*stockIn* documents

```json
 {
   serial:"stk0001",
   date:'2021-06-11',
   productInTransation:[
       {
         _id:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb1",
         productId:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb2"
         qty:2
       },
       {
        _id:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb1",
        productId:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb1",
        qty:2
       }

    ]
 }
```

and I have a *products* collection

```json
[
  {
   _id:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb5",
   name:"sepatu"
  },
  {
   _id:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb4",
   name:"sendal"
  }
]
```

so what I expect from those documents is just like below

```json
 {
   serial:"stk0001",
   date:'2021-06-11',
   productInTransation:[
       {
         _id:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb1",
         productId:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb2"
         qty:2,
         product:
           {
              _id:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb5",
              name:"sepatu"
           },
       },
       {
        _id:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb1",
        productId:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb1",
        qty:2,
        product:
          {
             _id:"60ae220b066b8d9861118cb4",
              name:"sendal"
          }
       }

    ]
 }
```

> this collection is just simplified from the real case.

and the problem I don't know how to do a query on mongodb, so the output will same as the expected. thank's for any help

Comment: What you tried so far? 
 They have clearly explained everything with code samples. Give it a try, If you hae any issue with the code, Then ask. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: thanks, bro. I just have try `lookup` from level one of the documents object, when I try in an array of sub-collection, I don't see what I expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lookup`

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$lookup` to join collections
- `$ifNull` to make sure this doesn't give any NPE when we take from first element from the joined array using `$arrayElemAt`
- `$group` to reconstruct the array

Here is the code

```
db.stockIn.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$productInTransation" },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "productInTransation.productId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "productInTransation.product"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "productInTransation.product": {
        "$ifNull": [ { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$productInTransation.product", 0 ] }, [] ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "date": { "$first": "$date" },
      "serial": { "$first": "$serial" },
      "productInTransation": { $push: "$productInTransation" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/26fhGUZHS9f)**